# Unknown SQL type - -98( because of Blob data from db2)

Tags: sql, telerik-reporting

I use db2 database with Odbc data provider and Telerik Report Designer Q3 2013.
I have a table which has a blob data of a picture. When I tried to select it, I take an error "Unknown SQL type - -98".
I can't find any documentation or solution about it. Can you please help?

Error Screen Shot

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=l9wnp&s=5#.UuuDEfl_vgw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odbc data provider is not support blob data type at DB2. I suggest you OleDB data provider.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, ODBC .Net data provider doesn't support this, but there is a workaround if you look [`here`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/r0011829.html)...

> **Workaround**
>
> Set the CLI/ODBC LongDataCompat keyword to 1. Doing so will
>   force the CLI driver to make the following data type mappings to data
>   types the ODBC .NET Data Provider will understand:
>
> - SQL_CLOB to SQL_LONGVARCHAR
> - SQL_BLOB to SQL_LONGVARBINARY
> - SQL_DBCLOB to SQL_WLONGVARCHAR
>
> To set the LongDataCompat keyword, run the following
>   DB2 command from a DB2 command window on the client machine: db2
>   update cli cfg for section common using longdatacompat 1 You can also
>   set this keyword in your application, using the connection string as
>   follows:
>
> **[C#]**
>
> `OdbcConnection con =   new
>   OdbcConnection("DSN=SAMPLE;UID=uid;PWD=mypwd;   LONGDATACOMPAT=1;");`
>
> For a list of all the CLI/ODBC keywords, refer to the "UID CLI/ODBC
>   configuration keyword".